# Are Keras sample_weights normalized internally or used as is?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm aware that sample_weights can be passed as third returned value from the generator. What I'm not clear about is how those weights are used internally: More specifically are those weights applied on the loss as-is, or is there any sort of normalization done internally (e.g. to make the weights add up to one for the entire data or each mini batch, etc).

In my use case I have weights for the entire dataset, and I would like to use them without any sort of postprocessing, to make sure the weights stay consistent globally. An undesirable behaviour in this case would be if internally the weights get normalized per batch for example.

Any pointer how I can get to the bottom of this would be highly appreciated.

I searched around but could not find anything related to this particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `sample_weights` are used as-is. The error for each sample is multiplied with the corresponding sample weight before mean (or other reduction method) is computed.

Consider `BinaryCrossEntropy` with `sample_weights` with `reduction` set to `none`:

```
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction='none')


y_true = [[0, 1], [0, 0]]
y_pred = [[-20, 0.5], [3, -10.]]

# without sample_weights
bce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
#[0.23703845 1.5243164 ]

#with sample weights
bce(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=[100, 10]).numpy()
# [23.703844 15.243164]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Does that mean the weights could even be negative numbers (can't think of an application but theoretically speaking)?

Comment: Yes. From the above example you can see that 100 is multiplied with the first error and 10 is multiplied with the second error. The weights can be anything, it just multiplies those before it averages.